# Orientation-preserving order on vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, orientation

Given a finite-dimensional real vector space V, is there a total order O on the vectors in V such that any basis of V, when ordered according to O, has the same orientation?

Does existence depend on the dimensionality of the vector space? If so, in which way?

Whenever such an order exists, how can (a simple) one be constructed?

If there is no such order, I would be interested in any generalization: for example a simple rule to order any basis in V such that it always leads to the same orientation.

Comment: I think I found a simple rule for 2D: Pick a coordinate representation of the space. Given a base consisting of two vectors, start with the vector that is on the right hand side of the smaller angle (the one that is smaller than pi) between them. I'm not sure how to generalize it to n dimensions.

Comment: Your rule for 2D is correct and it shows that a total order on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the properties you asked for does not exist: for example, thinking of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the complex numbers, and letting $\omega = e^{ \frac{2 \pi i}{3}}$, the bases $\{ 1, \omega \}, \{ \omega, \omega^2 \}$, and $\{ \omega^2, \omega^3 = 1 \}$ all have the same orientation, so the order would have to satisfy $1 < \omega < \omega^2 < 1$.

Comment: It seems I should have asked for a cyclic order, rather than a total order...